# GenericForeignKey( TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'object_id_fields'

Tags: python, django, hit-count

I am building a blog and I want to count any users that visit my page and  display numbers of

users that visit that page. and display content by populated.
I am using `GenericForeignKey` to access the model on my `hitcount` package

based on the documentation of `hitcount` packages. After I finish creating my models and try to run my sever I got this errors below .

> > File "F:\professional blog in django\BLOG\blog\blogapp\models.py",
> > line 48, in Post
> > site_visitor = GenericForeignKey( TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'object_id_fields'

is there any thing i am not doing right
please help

**`model.py`**

```
    from django.db import models from django.contrib.auth.models import
    User from datetime import datetime, date from django.db.models.fields
    import related from django.urls import reverse from
    django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey from
    hitcount.models import HitCountMixin, HitCount
    # Create your models here. from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError 

    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        author = models.ForeignKey(
            User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        body = models.TextField()
        category = models.ForeignKey(
            Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
        date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to="image", validators=[image_vailid])
        likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="like_post")
        site_visitor = GenericForeignKey(
            HitCountMixin, object_id_fields="object_pk", content_type_field="content_type")

     def numbers_of_likes(self):
         return self.likes.count()
 
     def __str__(self):
         return self.title + '| ' + str(self.author)
 
     def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse("home")
```

**`Error:`**

```
     File "F:\professional blog in django\BLOG\blog\blogapp\models.py",
     line 48, in Post
        site_visitor = GenericForeignKey( TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'object_id_fields'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly what it says: you're trying to create a class with a keyword argument that this class doesn't accept [(source)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/contenttypes/fields/):

```
class GenericForeignKey(object):
    # truncated
    def __init__(self, ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_id", for_concrete_model=True):
```

As you can see the `GenericForeignKey` class only accepts 3 arguments (other than the class): `ct_field`, `fk_field` and `for_concrete_model`. So only these three can be used as keyword arguments.

You need to either pass the arguments without their keyword, or make sure that you're passing this argument in the correct place. Start with the django documentation and [API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

If you're not understanding the difference between keyword and positional arguments, go to the python docs pages: [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument).

Edit:
this is the wrong part in your code:

```
site_visitor = GenericForeignKey(
            HitCountMixin, object_id_fields="object_pk", content_type_field="content_type")
```

Please read the links I have provided for you.

Comment: please i will appreciate if   you edit my code above to indcate where am going wrong and where i am not getting it.

Comment: @skylineguru added the wrong section to my answer.

Comment: i am  going through the link now